# Solving a first order differential equation involving $\sin(x/y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation
$$
y'\left(x\right) - \frac{y\left(x\right)}{2x} =
x\sin\left(x \over y\left(x\right)\right)
$$
I think it is separable variable differential equations. I tried to substitute: 
$$z=\frac{x}{y}$$
and $$y'=\frac {z-z'x}{z^2}$$
$$\frac {z-z'x}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}=x\sin(z)$$

multiply by $z^2$

$$z-z'x -\frac{z}{2}=z^2x\sin(z)$$

And now I have no idea how to manipulate this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $t=\dfrac{y}{x}$ ,

Then $y=xt$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=t+x\dfrac{dt}{dx}$

$\therefore t+x\dfrac{dt}{dx}-\dfrac{t}{2}=x\sin\dfrac{1}{t}$

$x\dfrac{dt}{dx}=x\sin\dfrac{1}{t}-\dfrac{t}{2}$

$\left(x\sin\dfrac{1}{t}-\dfrac{t}{2}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.